# How do I find points of intersection with tikz datavisualization

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to illustrate the differences between two payments (one of which is fixed and ends after a certain number of years and one of which inflates over time).

Now, my problem is an embarrassing one (and that's setting aside the absurd amount of time it took me to figure out how to get these two (very basic) graphs together)---I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to interact with the data I have visualized.

Mostly because I can't figure out how to implement anything like a name and I can't figure out how to reference them as paths...and nothing I've been able to Google talks about finding points of intersection, shading between two functions, or anything like that with the `datavisualization` library.

The manual talks about using `info` to maintain access to the coordinate system...but I can't find anywhere people are performing calculations on it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization,datavisualization.formats.functions,positioning}

\def\pOne{200}
\def\endYear{25}
\def\pTwo{150}
\def\inflation{5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \datavisualization [scientific axes,
                      visualize as line/.list={payment1,payment2},
                      payment1={pin in data={text={payments end},when=x is 25}},
                      all axes={padding=.5em},
                      x axis={label={years},
                              length=10cm,
                              ticks={step=5,
                                     minor steps between steps=4}},
                      y axis={label={monthly payment},
                              attribute=y,
                              scaling=min at 0cm,
                              length=10cm,
                              ticks={tick prefix=\$,
                                     step=50,
                                     minor steps between steps=4}},
                      ]
    data [set=payment1] {
      x, y
      0, 200
      25, 200
      25, 0
      35, 0
    } % why can't I use \pOne (or a comment) here?
    data [format=function,set=payment2] {
      var x : interval [0:35]; % is there a way to make this (non-)inclusive?
      func y = \pTwo*(1+(\inflation/100))^\value x);
    }
    info{
      % intersection
      % distances
      % areas between
      % etc.
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: You can add `\pgfmathsetmacro{\intersectionx}{ln(200/\pTwo)/ln((1+(\inflation/100)))} \draw [red] (visualization cs: x={\intersectionx}, y={200}) circle [radius=1pt];` to the `info` part which would get you the intersection. I am not sure whether it is possible to use the `intersections` library in this context.

Comment: I don't know whether this would be a solution for you, but using PGFPlots would allow you to use the `intersections` library to find intersections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure how the internals of this library work. At least using something like `payment1={style={name path global=path1}}` seems not to result in an accessibly named path which one could use later together with `name intersections`.

Two things come to my mind. First, you could add a label to the relevant coordinate (at *y* = 200) which cou can name and later access. However, this requires you to set the sample size in such a way that a coordinate is more or less exactly on the right *x* value which is not exactly trivial:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization, datavisualization.formats.functions}

\def\pOne{200}
\def\endYear{25}
\def\pTwo{150}
\def\inflation{5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \datavisualization [
    scientific axes,
    visualize as line/.list={payment1, payment2},
    payment1={
        pin in data={text={payments end}, when=x is \endYear},
    },
    payment2={
        label in data={when=y is \pOne, node style={anchor=center, name=intersection}},
    },
    all axes={padding=.5em},
    x axis={
        label={years},
        length=10cm,
        ticks={
            step=5, 
            minor steps between steps=4}
        },
    y axis={
        label={monthly payment},
        attribute=y,
        scaling=min at 0cm,
        length=10cm,
        ticks={
            tick prefix=\$, 
            step=50, 
            minor steps between steps=4}
        },
    ]
    data [set=payment1] {
      x, y
      0, \pOne
      \endYear, \pOne
      \endYear, 0
      35, 0
    } 
    data [format=function, set=payment2] {
      var x : interval [0:35] samples 101; 
      func y = \pTwo*(1+(\inflation/100))^\value x);
    }
    info{
      \draw[red] (intersection) circle[radius=2pt];
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second, more exact, solution would be to transform the formula that you use to plot the curved line and this way calculate the value for *x* for *y* = 200 (since you know this value in this case and it is stored in `\pOne`):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization, datavisualization.formats.functions}

\def\pOne{200}
\def\endYear{25}
\def\pTwo{150}
\def\inflation{5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
  \datavisualization [
    scientific axes,
    visualize as line/.list={payment1, payment2},
    payment1={
        pin in data={text={payments end}, when=x is \endYear},
    },
    all axes={padding=.5em},
    x axis={
        label={years},
        length=10cm,
        ticks={
            step=5, 
            minor steps between steps=4}
        },
    y axis={
        label={monthly payment},
        attribute=y,
        scaling=min at 0cm,
        length=10cm,
        ticks={
            tick prefix=\$, 
            step=50, 
            minor steps between steps=4}
        },
    ]
    data [set=payment1] {
      x, y
      0, \pOne
      \endYear, \pOne
      \endYear, 0
      35, 0
    } 
    data [format=function, set=payment2] {
      var x : interval [0:35]; 
      func y = \pTwo*(1+(\inflation/100))^\value x);
    }
    info{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ix}{ln(\pOne/\pTwo)/ln((1+(\inflation/100)))} 
        \draw[red] (visualization cs: x={\ix}, y={\pOne}) circle[radius=2pt];
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that a line created using `datavisualization` may not necessarily be a single path, but it can consist of different paths. Therefore, the approach of naming a path won't lead to anything anyways ... I might be wrong though.